# Phonegap/Cordova iOS Statusbar Back Button Displayed - Unexpected Behavior

Tags: ios, cordova, ios-statusbar

I am facing one issue on cordova app built for iOS. I am using cordova 5.1.1. When i double tap for few times on status bar of cordova app one back button appears on left top corner of the screen. This is unexpected behaviour for my app. Is it a known issue? If so how to get rid of this problem.

[image]

Comment: I've never seen that button on a cordova app, did you install any plugin?

Comment: Yes i have added a plugin and that was causing this problem. I have removed it from plugin and now it works fine.